# Scene Builder Inspector

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using `Scene Builder` and I would like to replicate the inspector look

[image]

**My questions:**

1. Are Padding, size, position areas ...etc panels within a `Scroll Pane` or are just two separators with a label in between ? It looks like a `Swing` `TitledBorder` `Jpanel`.
2. In case of panels, what has been used and how to set a title ?
3. In case of separators, how to set solid separator line instead of dashed as default? I have looked at the CSS analyser but can't find the right CSS statement.
4. Is there a naming convention for `fx:id` field? I have only find some examples all written in lowercase such as "maintabbedpane".

Comment: The Separator Line CSS is as followed:
`.separator .line {
    -fx-border-style: solid;
}`

Comment: are there any changes, do you have a solution?

Comment: Your suggestion works properly for separator, I have set a css file and it is all right. I am still waiting for answers to my other questions